# how to pass IP Address with form data in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Is there any way to pass ip address with form data in jsp page thanks in advance.
should we use hidden field to send it with form data

Comment: You shouldn't need to send the ip address, the server can get it from the request directly. Otherwise, you would send it just like you would any other string.

Answer (score 0):

An IP address can be represented as a string, so you can include it as the value of a hidden input if you like.

If you want the IP address that the request is coming from, then that will be exposed via `request.getRemoteAddr()` and you don't need to duplicate it in the form data.